# Flask - TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'BaseQuery' and 'int' in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I am attempting to create a "login" system, the quotations are because there's no security what so ever.

My current code is as followed:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.form['user'] or not request.form['password']:
            flash('Please enter all the fields', 'error')
        else:
            username = request.form['user']
            password = request.form['password']

            exists = db.session.query(User.user).filter_by(
                user=username)
            if exists > 0:
                logged_in = True
                session['username'] = username
                session['logged_in'] = True
                return index(exists=exists)
            return render_template('login.html', exists=exists)
        return render_template('login.html')
    return render_template('login.html')
```

However, I get the error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'BaseQuery' and 'int'
```

Which I don't understand because `exists` should return an integer.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that `exists` should be an integer?

Comment: But you didn't actually call an `exists()` method. You just named your query variable "exists".

Comment: I assumed exists would return how many is there. I guess not.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I wasn't sure I had to, where would I call it? in the if statement?

Comment: You are comparing an instance of `BaseQuery` with an `int`. If your query had `.all()` then you could have `if len(exists) > 0`.

Comment: @roy , when I print, exists it doesn't print anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exists = db.session.query(User.user).filter_by(user=username)` is a BaseQuery object, when you print exists it returns the SQL query. You are trying to compare a `BasQuery` instance and an `int` hence the error.

```
>>> exists = db.session.query(User).filter_by(username='me')
>>> exists
<flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery object at 0x7fbbb7812b70>
>>> type(exists)
<class 'flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery'>
>>> type(0)
<class 'int'>
>>> print(exists)
SELECT user.username AS user_username 
FROM user 
WHERE user.username = ?
```

If you want to check whether `exists` is greater than zero, you should add [.all()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.all) at the end of the query then use `len(exists)` since it returns a list.

```
>>> exists = db.session.query(User).filter_by(username='me').all()
>>> exists
[<User 1>]
>>> len(exists)
1
>>> type(len(exists))
<class 'int'>
```